# unable to connect to sqlserver database via jdbc

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

I want to connect my database named aaa via jdbc. I tried using type 1 driver and wrte this quote but the error"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length"
type 1 code :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("first");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:trial","sa","qwerty");
            System.out.println("second");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Then i tried using type 4 driver and i'm getting a compilation error with the getConnection() method
type 4 code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

class t {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("first");
            Connectin con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=aaa","sa","qwerty");
            System.out.println("second");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Please can some one help me out with these two problems

Answer (score 1):

In your second example there is a typo: `Connectin con=...` to `Connection con=...`!